# What to use as delegate and data source for a table view subview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` as a subview in a `UIViewController`. I am not sure if I can just create a `UITableViewController` as it is not a whole new "window"; it is simply a subview.

Correct if I am wrong, but the best thing to do is to create a class and set it as the delegate and data source for the `UITableView`.

What are all the things I need to do to set it up? Based on what I have seen in Apple's documentation, I need to adopt the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. I also read somewhere that I need to inherit from the `UIResponder` class, but I am not sure.

Is there anything else necessary for setup? Or is it more suitable to use a `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already noticed, creating whole `UITableViewController` is an unnecessary overhead.

What you need is just to implement required methods of `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. Then instantiate `UITableView`, set its delegate and data source appropriately, and display it.

Comment: Is that all I need to do? [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) in the first paragraph it suggests that it should inherit from UIResponder. What are the advantages of doing that?

Comment: Take a look at what is written there:  " The **delegating** object is often a responder object—that is, an object inheriting from NSResponder in AppKit or UIResponder in UIKit—that is responding to a user event. " In your case, the delegating object is UITableView, which is derived (indirectly) from UIResponder. But being, or being not a subclass of UIResponder has nothing to do with delegate, as delegate is a design pattern, which can be applied to any kind of class/object hierarchy, as long as it conforms to choosen contract.

Comment: Ohhhh, it was talking about the delegating object. I should start paying more attention to what I'm reading. Thanks so much!